# R function to calculate number of runs in a sequence of numbers

Tags: r

I have this sequence of numbers,

```
c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 
1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
-1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 
-1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 
-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
-1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 
1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 
-1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 
1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 
-1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1)
```

Now I want to calculate the number of runs in this sequence. Ideally I am expecting the result as `291`.

Is there any function to calculate the number of `runs`?

Comment: I count 109 runs, what exactly is a run for you?

Comment: @user2974951 It seems $291=400-109$ so $291$ is the number of terms equal to their predecessor

Comment: I had a deleted answer here that is gone after migration from StackExchange to StackOverflow. It is not visible to me anymore, but can anybody with more reputation see it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your vector is `x`, you can use the `rle` function:

```
rle(x)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:109] 34 3 2 1 5 1 2 1 2 5 ...
  values : num [1:109] 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 ...
```

but are you sure the result should be 291?

Comment: so `length(rle(x)$length)` gives 109, as does `1+sum(diff(x)!=0)`

Comment: while `sum(rle(x)$length - 1)`  gives 291, as does `sum(diff(x) == 0)`  which is the number of terms equal to their predecessor

Comment: ...which is the number of runs of length 2.  Perhaps that is what OP means.

Comment: @Henry thanks for this information. Looks like this is the correct one. But I think `length(rle(x)$length)` should be conceptually correct as per the common definition of `run`